# Can't fetch database objects when extending to another twig template in Symfony2

Tags: database, templates, symfony, fetch, twig

I'm new to Symfony2 (with knowledge in 1.2-1.4) and having little trouble trying to fetch some objects from the DB. I have a base template (index.html.twig) which have the following code block:

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>

{% for category in categories %}  
<li><a href="{{ category.name }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

<li class="last-item"><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The method fetching categories is inside DefaultController:

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $categories = $em->getRepository('XxxYyyBundle:Category')->findAll();
        $genres = $em->getRepository('XxxYyyBundle:Genre')->findAll();

        echo $categories.$genres;

        return array('categories' => $categories, 'genres' => $genres);
}
```

If I access the page from Default it works perfectly, but if I try to access from another page that extends the template (using {% extends "XxxYyyBundle:Default:index.html.twig" %}) I get the following error:

**Variable "categories" does not exist in XxxYyyBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 53**

I tried all the options included in the book (% include, etc) with the only conclusion that from another pages indexAction() is not executed. I think that fetching items from the DB to include them in a menu is something usual, so if someone is familiar to this matter I'll be very grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to place a render tag in your layout and reference a controller that runs the queries and renders the menu fragment.

```
{% render 'SomeBundle:Menu:menu' %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kris, I've tried that indeed, following the example from the book. I've created a menuAction() in default with indexAction code from above, and replaced at the end with return $this->render('XxxYyyBundle:Default:menuList.html.twig', array('categories' => $categories)); being menuList the page with the menu code block, but got exactly the same result. That's why I put the echo inside the method, to know if the app even enters it. When I load the page from Default it echoes "ArrayArray", but entering from another page that extends from index it shows nothing.

Comment: Solved! I forgot to delete the for statement from index. It was just what you said, thank you very much!